# PHP variable does not work in mySQL query and I don't know why

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

When I echo the variable `$userz` it writes the good username in the webpage, when I use it in the mysql query it does not work. Why?

```
echo $userz; // write "Programmeur" on the web page 
$bdd->exec('UPDATE user SET status = \'registered\' WHERE username =' .$userz);// not working
$bdd->exec('UPDATE users SET status = \'registered\' WHERE username = $userz');// not working 
$bdd->exec('UPDATE users SET status = \'registered\' WHERE username = \'Programmeur\'');//work
```

Is it because I'm using `wamp`  or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Because your `username` is probably a `varchar` and you don't quote it in your query.

`$bdd->exec('UPDATE user SET status = \'registered\' WHERE username = "' .$userz . '"');// working`

The best way to diagnose why your query isn't working, print `MySQL` error (both code and message), don't guess what is wrong. I think your `MySQL` wrapper can do this. I could tell for sure if I knew that exactly you are using here (what `$bdd` is instance of).

Comment: You are welcome. It's 4:26 PM in my city ;)

Answer (score 0):

in PHP, contents within single quotes will NOT be parsed.

You can use this:

```
$bdd->exec("UPDATE users SET status = 'registered' WHERE username = '$userz'");
```

Please consider the risk of SQL Injection. Use prepared statement if necessary.

*Also, what is your database table name? `user` or `users` ?*

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrapping the value in apostrophes:

```
username = \'' . $userz . '\''
```

Or perhaps more easily

```
$bdd->exec("UPDATE user SET status = 'registered' WHERE username = '$userz'");
```

What you should really do is use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.  Then, the quotes would be added for you automatically *and* the argument would be properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bdd->exec ( 'UPDATE user SET status = "registered" WHERE username = "'.$userz.'"' );
```

or

```
$bdd->exec ( "UPDATE user SET status = 'registered' WHERE username = '{$userz}'" );
```